# IOS push notifications using AWS, SNS with PHP

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Im trying to create a push notification using the AWS PHP SDK.  I am able to create a endpoint with a token and user date set (Unique ID) using php and it uploads fine to SNS.

```
$SNSEndPointData = $client->createPlatformEndpoint([
'PlatformApplicationArn' => "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:706219876456:app/APNS_SANDBOX/Mosdev",
'CustomUserData' => $userID,
'Token' => $deviceToken
]);
```

After I run this script my SNS dashboard shows it posted fine showing the Token and User Data.  From the SNS dashboard I am able to send push notifications to my IOS device.  But what I am trying to figure out is how can I send a Push Notification from my server using php not the SNS dashboard. I just want to target a certain user.  How would this be accomplished?

Comment: you get any solution?